# Any way to limit values without the use of if statements?

Tags: c#, image-processing

I'm working on a program that works with images.
I'm having trouble on a function that adjusts contrast and brightness.
I need to calculate a value for each RGB component based on what input I recieve from the user. 
The problem is, I need to make sure the final value after said calculation isn't greater than 255 or less than 0. So it can fit inside a byte.

```
temp = c * dataPtr[0] + b; //variable temp is of type double.

if (temp > 255)
{
    temp = 255;
}
else if (temp < 0)
{
    temp = 0.0;
}

dataPtr[0] = (byte)(Math.Round(temp));
```

I'm repeating this for every RGB component of every pixel, so the ifs are getting executed a million times, most of the times needlessly.

I thought about just casting a double back to byte but it just reads the first byte of the double and doesn't max out the value if it's greater than what a byte can handle.
Is there any obvious way to optmize this this range-check that I'm just missing?
Thank you.

Comment: I think you should show what `b` and `c` are as well...

Comment: They're completely irrelevant for the question in hand. It's just a calculation that may sometimes result in values greater than 255 or lesser than 0; If so, it should be maxed out at 255 or 0 respectively.

Comment: You could do `temp = Math.Max(0, Math.Min(255, temp));`, which is less typing but no fewer conditions being executed.

Comment: @RufusL  The conundrum here is reducing execution time. 
I thought the ifs were the ones adding overhead but it turns out the Math.round is the operation that's actually slowing it down.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. The `if` statements should be pretty fast, but looking at the source for [`Math.Round`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/f0afe85387e48317.html), there's a lot more going on there.

Comment: If you don't mind always rounding down, casting to an `int` is almost twice as fast as `Math.Round`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683442/where-can-i-find-the-clamp-function-in-net.  Depending on what you're targeting you may also have [System.Math.Clamp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.clamp?view=netcore-2.0), but as others have said there's nothing "wrong" with `if`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. `if` is the "gold standard" way of comparing values. If you need to make sure the the value is in a range `if` is the way to do it.
If you must have an alternative: use an existing type that can only handle values 0-255, but then "overflow" behavior is "less defined". If you make your own type it probably uses `if` inside it anyway.

Your reasons "lots of needless ifs" is nothing to worry about.