# Decode zero-terminated UTF-8 string from any position in a byte array

Tags: .net, string, utf-8, arrays, decode

I am looking for a method in the [FCL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807880/bcl-base-class-library-vs-fcl-framework-class-library) similar to [`Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, index, count)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05cts4c3.aspx), but one that does not require a `count` argument and instead assumes that the string at the given index is null-terminated.

I am posting my current solution as an answer (see below), but am curious to see whether someone knows of a more elegant or better-performing approach.

Comment: I'm not aware of any method in the .NET Framework that works with 0-terminated UTF-8 strings. The [Marshal Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.aspx) works with 0-terminated strings but does no UTF-8 conversion; the [UTF8Encoding Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.utf8encoding.aspx) always expects a length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written my own method since I haven't found one in the FCL:

```cs
using System.Text;

string GetZeroTerminatedUTF8StringAt(byte[] bytes, int index)
{
    int zeroTerminatorIndex = Array.IndexOf<byte>(bytes, value: 0, startIndex: index);
    if (zeroTerminatorIndex >= index)
    {
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, index, count: zeroTerminatorIndex - index);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("index", "No zero-terminator found.");
    }
}
```

While this works, it has one minor issue: It is assumed that no character except `'\0'` will contain a `0` byte in the UTF-8 encoding. While this is actually the case, it would be nicer if that assumption were fully encapsulated inside the `Encoding.UTF8` class.