# How to know a c# class is user defined class or c# assembly class

Tags: c#

I have searched but failed to know how to check a class is user defined class or c#.net assembly class. Please help me in this point. When I work with assembly I need to know which classes are user define and which are not? I also need to know class attributes type.

Comment: ".NET Assembly Class" = ? A class that ships with the .NET framework? A class that ships with a common .NET library (not included in the .NET [BCL/FCL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/807880/bcl-base-class-library-vs-fcl-framework-class-library))? Not-a-class-I-wrote?

Comment: I need to know a class is user defined or not.

Comment: Defined by *which* user? Every class was created by *someone* (or by an automated request from such).

Comment: Custom class or not defined by .net framework.

Comment: What about a class in (eg.) EF, which if not shipped with the core .NET Framework?

Comment: I think you'd better do this the other way around instead of recognizing .Net framework classes , introduce .Net assemblies to your project (for example by getting their names from the Assembly folder).

Comment: Could you explain *why* you need to identify user defined classes? [Maybe there's an easier solution that someone can suggest](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 0):

Try by pressing F12, and check in class defination. Maybe it might help.

Comment: You are wrong. I am working in code why do I press F12.

Answer (score 0):

Not very clear what you mean, but if you examine

```
yourObj.GetType().Assembly.Location
```

(or `.CodeBase`) you will get a hint. You will need to match the string against expected locations.

You can also use attributes, for example:

```
var compAttr = yourObj.GetType().Assembly
    .GetCustomAttribute<AssemblyCompanyAttribute>();
var name = compAttr != null ? compAttr.Company : null;
```

which needs `using System.Refelection;`. (In older versions (.NET 4 and earlier) the syntax for reflection is a bit more complicated.)

If *you* make the "user-defined" code, you can apply a:

```
[assembly: MadeByMe]
```

to each of your projects (where `public class MadeByMeAttribute : Attribute` needs to be written). Then search for that attribute, as it is certain never to be present in BCL assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

You could opt to check the public key token of the assembly to check if it matches that of Microsoft:

Try this extension method:

```
public static bool IsMicrosoftAssembly(this Assembly assembly)
{
    return assembly.GetName().GetPublicKeyToken()
           .SequenceEqual(typeof(int).Assembly.GetName().GetPublicKeyToken());
}
```

Use it like this:

```
var n = typeof(YourType).Assembly.IsMicrosoftAssembly();
```